# Selection of cheapest products, for a variable quantity (hourly demand)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We have two tables:

- One with bids (price & quantity) by numerous suppliers, for every hour of
  the year.
- A second table listing total consumer demand for every hour (quantity)

We need to generate:

- A third table that lists all the cheapest supplier bids, but only for the quantity summing to total consumer demand. Eg while there might be 10 bids at quantity (1), only the cheapest 5 will be selected if demand for that hour equals (5).

There is only product, and it is homogeneous. The only relevant parameters are thus price and quantity. Prices are per unit of quantity (ie not the total of the whole quantity).

Example:

**Supplier bids (offered quantity)**

| Hour | Supplier | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Siemens | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | Siemens | 4 | 20 |
| 1 | Fuji | 7 | 20 |
| 2 | ABB | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | Hitachi | 2 | 15 |
| 2 | Siemens | 4 | 10 |

**Total demand**

| Hour | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 25 |

Then the generated table should look like this:

**Awarded bids (cheapest, totaling to demand)**

| Hour | Supplier | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Siemens | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | ABB | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | Hitachi | 2 | 15 |

As you can see, the sum of all bids in this table equals the total demand from the second table. Even if there are additional bids, these are not included here because demand is fulfilled.

Often, the sum of supplier bids won't exactly total demand, eg if demand is 100 but every quantity equals 30. In that case, the quantity for the last bid added to the table is 'cut-off' (ie, only the quantity to meet demand is taken from that bid).

We thought of handling this via PLSQL, following these steps:

1. We create a CURSOR that selects all bids for a certain hour, ordered by price
2. A loop INSERTs the bids into the new table, UNTIL the sum of the inserted bids (quantity) has reached total demand for that hour.
3. The process is repeated, by re-declaring the CURSOR in a loop that goes over every hour (over a period of 10 years, meaning about 90k iterations).

As we are simple economists with limited background in SQL, this seems the most straightforward way to handle this. However, it appears that this approach is very resource intensive. There are namely over 15 million rows of supplier bids, and the amount of hours to loop through are around 90 000.

We therefore were wondering if those among you who are more educated in SQL matters than us would have any suggestions as to our approach. Eg. - is this is the only way to handle this? Is there a better, more efficient way?

Comment: Is the price the price per item, or the price in total?  In other words, is `price=10, quantity=20` preferred to `price=5, quantity=5`?  If the price is the "total" price, do you modify the price when "cutting off?  In other words, if you have `price=9, quantity=30` and you only need 10, does that become `price=9, quantity=10` or `price=3, quantity=10`?  If demand goes unfilled, does it ever "carry over" to the following hour?

Comment: (i)The price is per unit of quantity, (ii) the price is not modified when cutting off, (iii) unfulfilled demand indeed does not carry over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions made...

- Unfulfilled demand does ***not*** carry over to the subsequent hour
- The `price` is the price `per item`  *(not the total price for the whole batch)*
- When "cutting off", only the *required* quantity is paid for *(not the quantity in the original bid)*

This reduces the algorithm to simply aggregating bids in ascending `price` order, until `sum(quantity)` exceeds `demand`

This can be worked out using analytic functions (also known as window functions) rather than loops.

- https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions

For example...

```
WITH
  hourly_cumulative AS
(
  SELECT
    demand.hour,
    demand.quantity    AS demand,
    bid.supplier,
    bid.price,
    bid.quantity       AS supply,
    SUM(bid.quantity)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY demand.hour
            ORDER BY bid.price
      )
        AS fulfilled_demand
  FROM
    demand
  LEFT JOIN
    bid
      ON bid.hour = demand.hour
)
SELECT
  hour,
  demand,
  supplier,
  price,
  supply  AS potential_supply,
  CASE
    WHEN fulfilled_demand > demand
    THEN supply - (fulfilled_demand - demand)
    ELSE supply
  END
    AS actual_supply
FROM
  hourly_cumulative
WHERE
  fulfilled_demand - supply < demand
```

Be sure that you have indexes on `hour`, and for the bids, preferably on at least `hour, price`.

- The indexes will make the joins cheaper
- If they match the PARTITION and ORDER in the window clause, they'll make that cheaper too

Comment: We will experiment with this over the next days and provide feedback on the results. Many thanks for your help, this is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe one point already: the price is actually the unit price (not for the whole of the quantity), but I understand this is what the query actually assumes? If not, could you please clarify what would have to change?

Comment: @BartDeMuynck - What about the other assumption?  If you accept a bid of `(price=5, quantity=30)` and only want `10` units *("cutting off"), would you be paying `5*10=50` or paying `5*30=150`?  That has a very pronounced effect on the algorithm you want/need.

Comment: Apologies, I see your point now. The supplier is remunerated at the unit price * the actual quantity, so in that example 5*10.

Comment: @BartDeMuynck Then the current code works for your needs, no need to change it.

Comment: This is incredibly good, 0,134s to calculate 1 day. Many thanks for your help! Three questions if I may: 1) How do I take into account the 'date' in this model (now it only checks hours)?; 2) How do I add additional columns from the supplier table in the end result? 3) What happens if bids have the same price? Can we instruct to rank such bids by supplier name (ASC and alternatively DESC as a sensitivity check)?

Comment: @BartDeMuynck That's a lot to ask in a comment.  Ask a new question and link to this one, with example data and example results for what you're trying to achieve (I'm not clear on some of what you asked, a new quesiton with examples will help imeasurably)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your tables' names, so I've called them `bids` and `demands`:

```sql
select
   b.Hour
  ,b.Supplier
  ,b.Price
  ,b.Quantity-greatest(0,(b.running_total_quantity-d.quantity)) as quantity
from
    (
      select 
         Hour,Supplier,Price,Quantity
        ,nvl(
          sum(Quantity)
            over( partition by Hour 
                  order by Price 
                  rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                ) 
         ,0) as running_total_quantity
      from bids
    ) b
    join demands d
      on  b.hour=d.hour
      and b.running_total_quantity<d.Quantity
order by b.hour,b.price,b.running_total_quantity
```

As you can see we calculate running total quantity for each row up to this row order by price, but not including a quantity of the current row. Then we join these results with `demands` by `hour` and until we get the required quantity.

Full test case with test data:

```sql
-- test data:
with
 bids(Hour,Supplier,Price,Quantity) as (
    select 1, 'Siemens' , 1, 10 from dual union all
    select 1, 'Siemens' , 4, 20 from dual union all
    select 1, 'Fuji'    , 7, 20 from dual union all
    select 2, 'ABB'     , 1, 10 from dual union all
    select 2, 'Hitachi' , 2, 15 from dual union all
    select 2, 'Siemens' , 4, 10 from dual
)
,demands(Hour,Quantity) as (
    select 1, 10 from dual union all
    select 2, 25 from dual
)-- end of test data
--main query
select
   b.Hour
  ,b.Supplier
  ,b.Price
  ,b.Quantity-greatest(0,(b.running_total_quantity-d.quantity)) as quantity
from
    (
      select 
         Hour,Supplier,Price,Quantity
        ,nvl(
          sum(Quantity)
            over( partition by Hour 
                  order by Price 
                  rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                ) 
         ,0) as running_total_quantity
      from bids
    ) b
    join demands d
      on  b.hour=d.hour
      and b.running_total_quantity<d.Quantity
order by b.hour,b.price,b.running_total_quantity
```

Results:

```
      HOUR SUPPLIER       PRICE   QUANTITY
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
         1 Siemens            1         10
         2 ABB                1         10
         2 Hitachi            2         15
```

Comment: We will experiment with this over the next days and provide feedback on the results. Many thanks for your help, this is much appreciated.